# Props undefined react

Tags: reactjs

Desde una tabla realizada con material-table tiene un link que lleva a otra pagina para editar la fila seleccionada.

El problema es que me lleva a una pagina con el formulario vacio, y aparece la siguiente leyenda en la consola

GET http://localhost:xxxx/api/Articulos/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

Se que esta enviando bien el id porque al poner un console.log, si se visualiza el id correspondiente a la fila, en el navegador tambien me muestra la ruta correcta

http://localhost:****/Articulo/edit/1

```
rowData.Id
1

rowData.Id
2

rowData.Id
3

rowData.Id
4
```

¿Cual podria ser el problema si la ruta si esta agrrando el id correcto pero al momento de buscar en los props manda undefined en el id?

Tabla

```
 <Router>
  <MaterialTable
  title="Articulos"
  columns={[
    {title:'Id', field:'Id',type: 'numeric' ,hidden:'false'},
    {title: 'articulo',field: 'articulo'},
    {title: 'descripcion', field: 'descripcion'},
    {title: 'precio',field:'precio',type: 'numeric'},
  ]} 
  data={articulos.Data}
  actions={[
    rowData=>({    
      icon:()=><Link to={`/Articulo/edit/${rowData.Id}`}><EditIcon/></Link>
    })
  ]}
  />
  </Router>
```

Componente

```
function EditarArticulo(props) {

    const [articulos, setArticulos]=useState({articulo: '',descripcion:'', precio:0})

    useEffect(function() {
        async function getArticulos() {
          try {
            const response = await  axios.get(`/api/Articulos/${props.match.params.Id}`);
            setArticulos(response.data);        
          } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
        getArticulos();    
      }, [props]);
```

Ruta

```
    <Switch>          
      <Route exact path="/Articulo/edit/:Id" component = 
        {EditarArticulo}/>
    </Switch>
```

Comment: podrías añadir la parte donde declaraste las rutas esta ruta quisiera comprobar que la tienes /Articulo/edit/:Id

Comment: @VictorAlvarez si la tengo declarada de esa manera, ya agregue esa parte a la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías reemplazar Link por usar el history que viene en las propiedades

si estas usando clases seria: `this.props.history`

si estas usando hooks : `props.history`

```
<Router>
  <MaterialTable
  title="Articulos"
  columns={[
    {title:'Id', field:'Id',type: 'numeric' ,hidden:'false'},
    {title: 'articulo',field: 'articulo'},
    {title: 'descripcion', field: 'descripcion'},
    {title: 'precio',field:'precio',type: 'numeric'},
  ]} 
  data={articulos.Data}
  actions={[
      {
        icon: "iconname",
        onClick: (event, rowData) => this.props.history.push(`/Articulo/edit/${rowData.Id}`)
      }
  ]}
  />
</Router>
```

Comment: Ya no aparece el error  de undefined eso quiere decir que ya esta tomando el id correcto pero sigue saliendo el formulario vacio y con la siguiente advertencia : Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: Eso es una advertencia diferente a lo que hay en la pregunta, para poderte ayudar con eso te sugiero abras una pregunta nueva y adjuntes el código del componente EditArticulo, si te ayude marca este respuesta como aceptada y te ayudamos con la siguiente

Answer (score 1):

Revisando la documentación oficial de react-table, he encontrado que la manera en la que estás implementando el método no se parece mucho. Revisa https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions

Proponen el siguiente esquema de uso:

```
<MaterialTable
  // other props
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'save',
      tooltip: 'Save User',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        // Do save operation
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

Donde `rowData` contiene la información de las celdas de la fila sobre la que se ha hecho click.

Para el caso que usas, sería algo parecido al ejemplo que te muestro a continuación.

```
<Router>
  <MaterialTable
  title="Articulos"
  columns={[
    {title:'Id', field:'Id',type: 'numeric' ,hidden:'false'},
    {title: 'articulo',field: 'articulo'},
    {title: 'descripcion', field: 'descripcion'},
    {title: 'precio',field:'precio',type: 'numeric'},
  ]} 
  data={articulos.Data}
  actions={[
      icon: "iconname",
      onClick: (event, rowData) => <Link to={`/Articulo/edit/${rowData.Id}`}><EditIcon/></Link>
  ]}
  />
  </Router>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Lo intente implementar de esa manera pero no funciona el link, ni siquiera me muestra el formulario

Comment: Falta envolver los ítems del array entre {}, se me paso, pruébalo y me dices por favor

Comment: Si lo hice, porque si no sale error de sintaxis, asi quedo       `actions={[{
        icon: 'edit',
        tooltip: 'Edit',
          onClick:(event,rowData)=><Link to={`/Articulo/edit/${rowData.Id}`}><EditIcon /></Link>
        }
   ]}`

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un log de rowData y comprobar que tiene el campo `Id` que esperas?

Comment: Por alguna razon si pongo un console.log me sale error expected " ,"

Comment: es porque la función onClick no tiene `{}` debes poner `onClick:() => { console.log(rowData); return <Link .../> }`

Comment: Ya puse el console.log y si contiene el Id de los registros